# Exposing .csv via Wolfram Cloud API

Tags: csv-format, wolfram-cloud

I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish this, but my goal is to generate a .csv file from a running notebook, and have it accessible by API.

In the main program, I'm exporting the data like so:

```
CloudExport[csvTable,"CSV","outputFile.csv"];
```

From there, I'm able to access it and expose it using

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, StringForm[CloudImport["outputFile.csv","Text"]]],Permissions->"Public"]
```

When I do a CloudImport in a notebook (as text), the data looks correct.  But when I open it in the API, it is quoted and appended with [<||>]

Is there a better way to do this?  How can I prevent the additional characters from being added?  In the end I just want an external consumer to access and process the data.

thanks!

Comment: also, I can't CloudImport as "CSV" because the output will just be a Mathematica Array.

Comment: Well, it doesn't exactly solve the problem, but it helps with _my_ problem.  I think I can skip the additional API step by doing CloudExport[csvTable,"CSV","outputFile.csv",Permissions->"Public"];